# chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'merge')

Tags: angular, chart.js

Need callout labels for the pie chart. I'm trying to make `chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels` work with Chart.js version 4x.

First, `import PieChartOutLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels';` generates error:

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels'. 'C:/project/node_modules/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels/dist/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels';`
```

After created a `typings` folder, added `chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels';
```

`tsconfig.app.json` has `"include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]`, error becomes

Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'merge')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'merge')
at chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels.js:22:25
at chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels.js:11:65
at 2818 (chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels.js:10:2)

Anyone knows how?